# Help controlling the cursor in swype?

Tags: swype

I've got swype pre-installed on my Epic4G, and after a recent update (which also introduced an exasperating auto correction "feature") I'm finding that my cursor won't stay put -- it pops to the end of the word instead of staying where I set it. Say I type `twowords` and then realize I need a space -- I go set the cursor between `two` and `words` thinking that I'll hit the space bar and separate them, but the cursor, which definitely landed where I wanted it, hops to the end of `twowords`. If I try *again* it stays, but the first time it consistently hops to the end of the word.

Is there a setting for this anywhere?

Comment: When does this happen? I recall seeing it in the web browser, but not in any other applications.

Comment: Are you on the latest version of Swype?   I remember this happening on my Droid (2.2.2), but I believe it stopped with a Swype upgrade.   I'm on a new phone now, so I can't double check it.   It definitely does not behave that way on my Droid Bionic on 2.3.

Comment: @SaintWacko It happens in any application. I haven't noticed any difference between applications.

Comment: @TomG I have Swype 3.4.82.25814.25877.

Comment: You may want to check whether there's a newer version of Swype for your phone -- my Droid (Android 2.2.2) has Swype 3.6.84.2668.t100.26699 and my Bionic (2.3.4) has 3.25.91.34176.342744391.Targa_Ver4.

Comment: @TomG ... if you offer that as an answer and tell me how I'd go about checking for a newer version of Swype (it was preinstalled) you could get an answer accepted and I could update swype.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if a preloaded version of Swype can be updated with a Beta or not, but  [beta.swype.com](http://beta.swype.com/) is the starting point for downloading the Swype installer, which will then download the actual Swype keyboard (you must register on beta.swype.com first).

Swype also has user forums, [this page](http://forum.swype.com/forumdisplay.php?62-Samsung) lists their Samsung-specific boards.  I took a quick look under the Epic section and didn't see anything applicable, but you may find more on a deeper search.

Answer (score 1):

Swype has something that they call the "editing keyboard", which pops up a d-pad, arrow keys, cut/copy/paste keys and other stuff. You can access it by swyping from the Swype key to the Num key.